# ZF2 EmailAddress validator

Tags: php, validation, email, zend-framework2

I am creating ZF2 email address validator via factory that has 2 parts, one checks if emaill is already in DB, two: validate the email.
Prblem is that my NoObjectExists validator works just fine, but the acatual Email address validator does not (validator recognises "dsfsfhsadjkfnaskl" as valid email). Here is my code, maybe you guys can spot what is wrong with it?

```
    $factory = new \Zend\InputFilter\Factory();

    $input =  $factory->createInput(array(
        'name' => 'email',
        'required' => false,
        'filters' => array(
            0 => array(
                'name' => 'Zend\Filter\StringTrim',
                'options' => array(),
            ),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            0 => array(
                    'name' => '\DoctrineModule\Validator\NoObjectExists',
                    'options' => array(
                        'object_repository' => $this,
                        'fields' => array('email'),
                ),
            1 => array(
                    'name' => '\Zend\Validator\EmailAddress',
                    'options' => array(
                        'allow' => \Zend\Validator\Hostname::ALLOW_DNS,
                        'domain' => true,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));

    return $input;
```

Comment: I actually was trying to give some advice and I put valuable time in adding an answer to your question. My answer actually got upvoted by someone else meaning it was considered useful by others. Instead of showing some appreciation and thanking me you instead decided to downvote my answer. Not a very respectful thing to do IMO. Your question actually did not apply to [the StackOverflow mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you should be happy people are even reading it. I removed my answer, so you got what you wanted but don't expect any help from me in the future. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your array nesting. You aren't closing off the containing the NoObjectExists validator so the Email validator is nested inside.

Try the following:

```
    $factory = new \Zend\InputFilter\Factory();

    $input =  $factory->createInput(array(
        'name' => 'email',
        'required' => false,
        'filters' => array(
            0 => array(
                'name' => 'Zend\Filter\StringTrim',
                'options' => array(),
            ),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            0 => array(
                'name' => '\DoctrineModule\Validator\NoObjectExists',
                'options' => array(
                    'object_repository' => $this,
                    'fields' => array('email'),
                ),
            ),
            1 => array(
                'name' => '\Zend\Validator\EmailAddress',
                'options' => array(
                    'allow' => \Zend\Validator\Hostname::ALLOW_DNS,
                    'domain' => true,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));

    return $input;
```

Comment: @Auris if you would make a habit of aligning your arrays you could prevent such issues in the future.

Comment: yes, that is what usually do, but when doing quick copy paste these things sometimes slip by :) anyhow, thnx.